# Htaccess cacheable redirect to index.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

Currently i'm using Apache .htaccess to redirect sub.domain.com/test/ to sub.domain.com/test/index.html (or .php) with the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

However, [GTmetrix.com](http://gtmetrix.com)'s performance test tells me:

> To speed up page load times for visitors of your site, remove as many landing page redirections as possible, and make any required redirections cacheable if possible.
>
> http: //sub.domain.com/test is a permanent redirect to http: //sub.domain.com/test

Is it possible to make this redirect cacheable? And if so, how?

Comment: The _internal_ redirect done by DirectoryIndex is not visible to clients/browsers/test tools. If there's a redirect, it's from a source other than DirectoryIndex.

* If it's a RedirectMatch, add a 301 as the first parameter
* If it's a RewriteRule, add R=301 to the flags.